# How to give credit to github repo’s owners

Tags: github

There’s two github project that I want to fork and merge but I don’t know how to do it and give the credits for the owners.

First I thought of forking one project and just manually merging with the other project but it’ll still be a fork of only the first project.

If I just manually merge (no forking) the two projects, what would be the right way to give credits to the owners of the repos ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to comply with the requirements of licenses that both repositories have.
Licenses often describe proper way of acknowledging ownership. Question about specific licenses can be best asked on opensource.stackexchange.com or law.stackexchange.com. Some licenses might not allow such a modification.

If there are no licensing blockers, remember to credit the authors by adding a section in README.md with links to original software.

Comment: Thank you! I'll make sure to do it properly